# Custom Return-Path for gmail domain

Tags: smtp, spf, gmail

I do not expect my problem to be super-unique, but I was not able to find and answer so far even at Gmail help pages, and lots of googling with various terms did not provided a solution.
Context:

There is company, lets say `BusyCorp LLC`, whose SaaS product and related emails are live in, lets say, in `product.com` domain.

They use Gmail for their normal emailing stuff, with default (sign-in domain) like `busycorp.com`
due some historical reasons, does not matter.

The `product.com` domain is configured as alias domain for their Gmail setup, so for example
their employees can send messages from addresses like `bob.parker@product.com` by selecting it from the aliases dropdown when they are composing emails at Gmail page.

The email, though have `Return-Path` header like `bob.parker@busycorp.com` which causes SPF mismatch even with default relaxed alignment for `product.com`.

Is there a way to setup some MX, A, TXT or SPF records, or apply some settings at Gmail to make sure that Return-Path will be like `bob-parker@product.com` or like `message-id@gm.product.com` as used for SES, to make sure that is SPF aligned?

Or changing main domain at the Gmail settings is single way to fix that?
Will there be some consequences of that switch, if so? like will they all be signed out of Gmail, Google Cloud Console, Google Analytics?

Best regards and thanks for your answers and time!

Comment: I have this exact question. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, sorry. Surprised still this issue not addressed by someone else and no solution sitill present.

Comment: Related question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120312/ -- suggests it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is caused by using STRICT mode for your SPF. If you change it to relaxed, then you will no fail authentication, as long as DKIM is properly setup.
I have tested and confirmed this, as I had the same issue. I have written an article explaining it here.
https://domainadmintools.com/dmarc-strict-vs-relaxed-alignment-how-to-fix-spf-alignment-failed/